# Google Analytics API V4 does not work with GA4 account

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

Is it possible to get data from new Google Analytics (GA4) accounts through API V4? It always returns the following error message:

```
{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "errors": [ { "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.", "domain": "global", "reason": "forbidden" } ], "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }
```

I can do it perfectly on UA accounts.

Is there any API (web server request - OAuth) specific to this new account type?

[property id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gui8G.jpg)

Here is the code used (PHP):

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/FILE.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
$analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);
$response = getReport($analytics);
printResults($response);

function getReport($analytics){
    
    $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
    $dateRange->setEndDate("today");
    
    $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $sessions->setExpression("name");
    $sessions->setAlias("sessions");
    
    $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request->setViewId('307566943');
    $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
    $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));
    
    $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
    $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
    
    return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
    
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and include [example]

Comment: @DaImTo Updated, the error persists :/

Comment: You are using the Google Analytics Reporting api that will only work with universal analytics accounts.  If you are trying to access GA4 then you need to use the Analytics Data API.    Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile

Means that the user you have authenticated your application with. Does not have permission to access the Google analytics view you are trying to extract data from.

The issue can also be caused if you are trying to use the Google Analytics Reporting API with a Google Analytics GA4 account. As GA4 property IDs are not the same as UA view IDs, the system gets confused and assumes you just don't have access.

The solution is to authenticate the app with a user that has access to that view or grant the user access. And to check that you are using the correct API for the type of Google Analytics you are trying to access.

## UA vs GA4

Also remember that to extract dates from a GA4 account, you need to use the [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1).  If you have extracted data from UA accounts, you have been using the [Google Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/). These are two completely different APIs with different methods.

## [Google Analytics Data API Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries)

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;

/**
 * TODO(developer): Replace this variable with your Google Analytics 4
 *   property ID before running the sample.
 */
$property_id = 'YOUR-GA4-PROPERTY-ID';

// Using a default constructor instructs the client to use the credentials
// specified in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient();

// Make an API call.
$response = $client->runReport([
    'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
    'dateRanges' => [
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '2020-03-31',
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]),
    ],
    'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
        [
            'name' => 'city',
        ]
    ),
    ],
    'metrics' => [new Metric(
        [
            'name' => 'activeUsers',
        ]
    )
    ]
]);

// Print results of an API call.
print 'Report result: ' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
    print $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()
        . ' ' . $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

## Load credentials file directly

```
// Authenticate using a keyfile path
$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient([
    'credentials' => $service_account_key_file_path
]);
```

Comment: Thanks. The code sent connects via service account, via oauth is it possible?

Comment: Service accounts are oauth2.  but if you mean requesting consent of the user yeah its using the google cloud client library.  You just need to swap out the authorization method to that of the standard oauth2 method.

Comment: Is it possible to authenticate with a google service account instead of the gcloud 2oauth with the `BetaAnalyticsDataClient`. With the PHP Google_Client for UA we could do something like `$client->setAuthConfig("Path/To/Key/File.json");`. Is this possible voor GA4 as well?

Comment: Sure its designed to do that out of the box.  just make sure you grant the service account access to the google analytics account.   Check edit